# Inbox resolution for ActivityPub outbox delivery

Tags: activity-streams, activitypub

Anyone experienced with the ActivityPub protocol who can clarify something for me?
For server-server federation (S2S), what's the correct delivery logic when something is addressed to a remote followers collection?

7.1 of the ActivityPub spec says:

> The inbox is determined by first retrieving the target actor's JSON-LD representation and then looking up the inbox property. If a recipient is a Collection or OrderedCollection, then the server MUST dereference the collection (with the user's credentials) and discover inboxes for each item in the collection

But that seems like it would incur a ridiculous number of GET requests to the remote server: one to get the JSON-LD for the Collection, then one for each item in the collection to retrieve *its* JSON-LD. It's even worse if the remote Collection is paged.

7.1.1 of the spec says (emphasis mine):

> When objects are received in the outbox (for servers which support both Client to Server interactions and Server to Server Interactions), the server MUST target and deliver to: The to, bto, cc, bcc or audience fields **if their values are individuals or Collections owned by the actor**.

This appears to contradict 7.1, when it says the server must dereference everything.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: I am not sure if stackoverflow is the best place for ActivityPub questions. You can consider creating a post on the [SocialHub](https://socialhub.activitypub.rocks) forum which is dedicated to AP development.